# iOS. How to get an information about current map rect after each action with this map?

Tags: ios, dictionary, position, mkmapview, rect

For example, I want to display the current x, y, width and height of the map rect, but I don't know what events should I handle. At least I want to catch the double click, zoom and dragging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation for the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol. You have these available methods: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html

```
– mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:
– mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:
– mapViewWillStartLoadingMap:
– mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:
– mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:withError:
– mapViewWillStartLocatingUser:
– mapViewDidStopLocatingUser:
– mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:
– mapView:didFailToLocateUserWithError:
– mapView:viewForAnnotation:
– mapView:didAddAnnotationViews:
– mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:
– mapView:annotationView:didChangeDragState:fromOldState:
– mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:
– mapView:didDeselectAnnotationView:
– mapView:viewForOverlay:
– mapView:didAddOverlayViews:
```

Also, `MKMapView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, so by setting yourself as the delegate, you can also adopt the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol, and use these methods: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html

Comment: I don't why do you post it here. I know about documentation and I asked if it is necessary to override ALL this functions???

Comment: It's not overriding, you implement the delegate methods you want to be notified about :) In particular you probably want to implement:     – mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated: and 
    – mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:

Comment: It is almost all I need. Maybe is it possible to track the event of dragging the current position until the event of "touches up"?